# UWP - Close my content dialog on click on the blank area

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have created a content dialog for my UWP app which involves a centralized UI Element and a surrounding blank area.But content dialog does not have a property like "IsLightDismissEnabled" to close the dialog on click on an area except the UIELEMENT area.How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

In the code behind your content dialog:

```
public sealed partial class CustomDialog : ContentDialog
{
    public CustomDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Boolean isHide;

        Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (isHide)
                Hide();
        };

        PointerExited += (s, e) => isHide = true;
        PointerEntered += (s, e) => isHide = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the Answer.  the other replies do not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are few options that I can think of:

- Use popup (like uruk suggested) and add your controls inside, create the popup at desired location (you could also use binding here if you want to show the popup at location depending on user input at runtime Popup has HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset properties)
- Create a parent view that is taking up the whole page but is transparent, then add your UI elements at the center and attach tap/click events to the transparent view. These events are going to just close remove/collapse the transparent view which contains the other elements inside (Either by binding of values or by setting the values to the UI elements).

Example or popup usage:

```
<Popup x:Name="MenuPopUp"
       IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
       HorizontalOffset="{Binding HorizontalOffset}"
       VerticalOffset="{Binding VerticalOffset}"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid>
            YOUR ELEMENTS HERE
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Content dialog is a modal dialog. Why don't you use a [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup) or a child class of it? It's non-modal, and it already has the IsLightDismissEnabled property you just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Popup x:Name="MenuPopUp"
       IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
       LostFocus="MenuPopUp_LostFocus"/>

In CS
private void MenuPopUp_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       MenuPopup.IsOpen = false;
}
```